# How to define Array Datatype in Angular 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

[image: I got in console not in UI screen]

My model:

```
    export class Customer
 {
        CustomerId :number
        FirstName : string
        LastName : string
        Email : string
        Phone : string
        ConfirmPassword:string
        Password : string
        Address : string//**I want to define address as array.Because I got List of Address from Customer  as shown in the image.**

        }
```

Got Array of Address from customer API.How to Achieve this?

Comment: `It display Like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] in UI`. That error does not change even if you declare it as `array`. If you are displaying array of objects in template the do it `{{Address | json}}`

Comment: It displays all the columns in address table.What if i do if i want to display one particular column?

Comment: You can loop through address array and display each item using `*ngFor`

Comment: Check updated answer so as to how to display array of objects and their individual items. You can check that demo aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a **Address** typescript class as follows.

```
export class Address {
  addressId: string;
  customerId: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Then define address array atrribute in **Customer** class.

```
export class Customer {
   customerId :number
   firstName : string
   lastName : string
   email : string
   phone : string
   confirmPassword:string
   password : string
   address : Address[];
```

}

Then iterate customers and their adress.

```
<ul *ngFor="let customer of customers">
  <li>
    <div>
      <strong>
        {{customer?.firstName}}
        {{customer?.lastName }}
      </strong>
      <span>-</span>
      <div *ngFor="let adr of customer?.address">
        {{ adr?.addressId + ', ' + adr?.customerId + ', ' + adr?.firstName}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1kmqqs

Comment: It's Working. Thk u

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
customers : Customer[] = [];
```

**EDIT:**

You need to have a class for Address as followes,

```
export class Customer
{
  AddressId : string;
  ... etc
}
```

and in your Cusomter class,

```
export class Customer
{
    CustomerId :number
    FirstName : string
    LastName : string
    Email : string
    Phone : string
    ConfirmPassword:string
    Password : string
    Address : Address[]

}
```

Comment: It display Like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] in UI

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Array<Address>` or `Address[]`, both are same.

If you do not have an `Address` model then simply use `Array<{}>`

```
export class Customer
{
    CustomerId :number
    FirstName : string
    LastName : string
    Email : string
    Phone : string
    ConfirmPassword:string
    Password : string
    Address : Array<Address>

}
```

EDIT :

To display each item inside an objects (contained in an array), you may simply loop through array of objects

```
<div *ngFor = "let addr of address">    
  {{addr.addressId}} |  {{addr.customerId}} |  {{addr.firstName}}
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfmxw2)

Comment: But where should the Address | json be given

Comment: `{{Address | json}}` is to  simply display the entire array without formatting. That is just for debugging purpose. Follow as mentioned in answer to access individual object items in an array.

Comment: See updated demo to get clear idea on that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfmxw2

Answer (score 0):

You have to define something like: `export interface Address {...}` and then in your Customer class you have to change the address property type from string to Adress[]